# Configure Ubuntu Server VPS to send mail without going to spam

Tags: ubuntu, imap, spam-prevention, postfix

I have installed and configured Postfix on a VPS.

I have managed to get it so I can send and receive mail.

However every time I send mail from It, it get's marked as spam and was wondering how I stop it been flagged as spam?

Also I can only check the mail from the server, how do I configure it into Outlook or Thunderbird or something like that?

Comment: Do you have an MX Record?

Comment: It looks like it is set to my domain name, is that correct?

Comment: Get yourself an SPF record...

Comment: I have used mxtoolbox and everything appears to be okay with the MX record, also I have set an SPF record, do I need to purchase one or something?

Comment: The final paragraph belongs in a separate question.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the IP address of your VPS is not on any of the common blacklists, and that it isn't an open relay? (Though IIRC Postfix is fairly sane by default.) You can't really configure your mail server so that other mail servers don't flag your mail as spam; broadly speaking, that's a policy decision of the recieving mail server. You need to figure out why they are flagging your mail as spam.

Comment: It's not on a blacklist, how do I check the open relay?